# What is windows miniport network adapter replacement in linux?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, network-adapter

we have received assignment at work which includes porting some product from windows to linux. Part of that product functionality is an NDIS6 miniport network adapter, which apparently only passes through network buffers. It has an identifier and MAC address. Separate service application activates that network driver and starts IP services that pass network traffic through this adapter.

My question is what would be functional replacement of such 'dummy' network driver on Linux?

Comment: Is the goal to create a _virtual_ network adapter connected to a program (much like VPN programs do), or to write a driver for a _physical_ network adapter, or to create a network adapter that isn't connected to anything at all? It seems that on Windows, miniport drivers are a generic framework so this doesn't really explain much about what _functionality_ you need from them.

Comment: @user1686 as far as I can tell, it is not connected to any physical network adapter. My knowledge about networking is little to none. What is the difference between _virtual_ network adapter and the one that is not connected to anything at all? Ideally, I am hoping that there are simply cli tools on linux with which it is possible to setup something that provides the same functionality.

Comment: Well, maybe none (they're both virtual, I suppose), but by "virtual" in this case I specifically meant ones that are controlled by program.

Comment: Ok, so I think we can assume this one is virtual. The way it works on windows is that the main program passes this network adapter string identifier to a windows api call which opens it and returns windows handle. Then it queries it for MAC address. With this MAC address regular IP interfaces are setup.

Comment: If you're looking for the WAN miniport (PPPOE), you might try [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147763/setup-wan-miniportpppoe-internet-connection): Run `sudo pppoeconf` and follow the prompts. See the post for more details.

Comment: @harrymc I'm afraid there is a term conflict with regard to "miniport". In this context miniport is a flavor of windows drivers.

Comment: @harrymc NDIS Miniport drivers https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/ndis-miniport-drivers2

Comment: You mean [ndis on Linux](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/4/ndis/)?

Comment: No, *nix ndis wrapper for ndis windows driver is not something we are currently contemplating.

Comment: @harrymc My original question is about a functional replacement. Some entity (module?) that will behave as a pass-through for ethernet packets, and which can be programmatically activated and deactivated, and which can be programmatically used to setup IP networking through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is windows miniport network adapter replacement in linux?

"Miniport network adapter" does not explain much – *miniport driver* is something rather specific to the Windows driver model, and describes how the driver was written, but not what it does.

> Some entity (module?) that will behave as a pass-through for ethernet packets, and which can be programmatically activated and deactivated, and which can be programmatically used to setup IP networking through it

If your goal is to create a network interface that is controlled by software (i.e. packets sent through the interface are received by a program through a filehandle, and vice versa), then you should use a **`tap`** or **`tun`** interface. (The former carries packets with a layer-2 Ethernet header, the latter without, but otherwise they're the same.)

- Official documentation:

  https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt

  (This documentation is quite old; in all modern Linux distributions you do not need to create device nodes by hand, nor load kernel modules manually. However, section 3 "Program interface" and the ioctl-based API is still accurate.)

TUN/TAP interfaces are used by most VPN and VM software on Linux; indeed the "TAP-Windows" and "Wintun" NDIS drivers that are available on Windows were written to imitate them.

It is also possible to write your own network interface driver which does the same (such as 'vboxnetadp' used by VirtualBox and 'sheep_net' used by the SheepShaver Mac emulator), but most sysadmins will thank you for not doing so and for using the standard tun/tap instead.

Comment: This might be it! I will pass this to the team, thanks!